# Automatically updating variables

Tags: c#, reference

I am having three `int` variables namely, `a1` , `a2` and `a3`. I want `a1` such that it is always sum of `a2` and `a3`. If I change values of `a2` or `a3`, then the value of `a1` should automatically get updated. How to achieve this ?

Comment: John Watson, please see if my change of title reflects the intention of your question. Rollback the edit otherwise.

Comment: You can do it with [reactive programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031611/is-reactive-programming-going-back-to-the-pass-by-reference)!

Answer (score 4):

@Randolf's right, have you considered putting them into a class instead and having a1 computed automatically, i.e.

```
public class IntHolder()
{
  public int a2 {get; set;}
  public int a3 {get; set;}
  public int a1
  {
   get
   {
     return a2+a3;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: +1 and fixed per @Baboon 's comment. Also added answer for local version if needed.

Comment: I have 54 variables like `a1`, is this method suitable

Comment: 54, seems a lot?! Can't think of a better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to update it manually. Since `int` is a [primitive type](http://geekswithblogs.net/ftom/archive/2008/09/04/c-or-.net-primitive-types-value-types-reference-types-and.aspx) it holds the value directly not a reference to. So, implement a method that, whenever either a2 or a3 change, then it sums both and assign its value to a1. Or just set a1 a readonly property which always calculate the value. But, for the first case:

```
private int m_a2;
public int A2
{
    get { return m_a2; }
    set
    {
        m_a2 = value;
        CalculateSumAgain();
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes A2 "know" that A1 uses it (a method is barely any abstraction in this case), and you need to do the same for A3. Why not let A1 manage itself?

Comment: @Baboon It seems clear from my answer "Or just set a1 a readonly property which always calculate the value. BUT, FOR THE FIRST CASE:" I answer both options but try to make it accord the OP, the second one is pretty obvious.

Comment: I have 54 variables like `a1`, will this method be suitable ?

Comment: @JohnWatson Sure it will be. Given that there are so many variables, this could be, indeed, the best option. Why? Well, because you're precalculating when variable changes. So, if this will go to UI is better to calculate ahead of the UI request (as you first try to). If not, well, then maybe it's better to try the second approach, but take in count that you'll be adding 54 variables each time. There's nothing wrong if they're just int but when you start messing up with other types, things get a little slower.

Answer (score 2):

Make a1 a property like:

```
public int a1
{
   get
   {
      return a2 + a3;
   }
}

public int a2;
public int a3;
```

Comment: I have 54 variables like `a1`, can this property be put inside a `for` loop ?

Comment: @JohnWatson you have 54 variables that are the sum of another 2 variables?

Answer (score 0):

And if you want it to be local to function - lambda for a1 would almost work - you can't have local property this way so have to use method call syntax for a1 like `a1()`:

```
void foo()
{
  int a2 = 3;
  int a3 = 4;
  Func<int> a1 = ()=> a2 + a3;
  Console.WriteLine(a1()); // 3+4 = 7
  a2 = 5;
  Console.WriteLine(a1()); // 5+4 = 9
}
```