# Is reactive programming going back to the pass by reference?

Tags: variables, reactive-programming, pass-by-reference

Today, I read, "... in an imperative programming setting, a := b + c would mean that a is being assigned the result of b + c in the instant the expression is evaluated, and later, the values of b and c can be changed with no effect on the value of a. On the other hand, in reactive programming, the value of a is automatically updated whenever the values of b or c change, without the program having to re-execute the statement a := b + c to determine the presently assigned value of a." in Wikipedia

Does this mean that reactive programming is going back to passing by reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactive programming doesn't pass data by reference, in the contrary it is an anti-pattern in Functional Reactive Programing.

The reason why the value of a is automatically updated whenever the values of b or c change, is because it's implementing the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Comment: Looks like I need to dig into design patterns.